# How to test method that runs async on main thread?

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing

I simply have a method:

```
func update(with process: PresentableProcess) {
    presentableProcess = process
    if isViewLoaded {
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            //do something on the main thread
        }
    }
}
```

And its test:

```
func testPreferredContentSizeWhenTitleExist() {
    let process = PresentableProcess(title: "title")
    sut.update(with: process)

    XCTAssertEqualWithAccuracy(sut.preferredContentSize, 95, accuracy: 10)
}
```

It doesn't work, because it runs on the main thread. I would like to avoid adding completion block in `update(with)` to pass a test.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you will need to use completion block. To test asynchronous functions use expectations

```
let expectation = expectation(description: "expectation")

doStuffWithCompletion() {
    expectation.fulfill()
}

waitForExpectations(timeout: 10) { error in
    //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method must have a completion block.
Then you can use an `Expectation` object

```
let urlExpectation = expectation(description: "GET \(url)")
let process = PresentableProcess(title: "title")
sut.update(with: process) {
    XCTAssertEqualWithAccuracy(sut.preferredContentSize, 95, accuracy: 10)
    urlExpectation.fulfill()
}
```

Or to avoid adding the completion block, you can create a protocol with a method called when setup is ended.